# Any ideas why this alphabetical string sorting doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sorting

I've been doing a program which does many things with car list, checking everything and the last thing I need to do is to sort those cars alphabetically by strings .Brand. Here's the code that's not working how it should be.

```
for (int j = 0; j < towns[townNo].townVehicleCount-1; j++) {
    for (int k = 1; k < towns[townNo].townVehicleCount; k++) {
        int identical;
        identical = towns[townNo].Vehicles[j].Brand.CompareTo(towns[townNo].Vehicles[k].Brand);
        if (identical == 1) {
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[towns[townNo].townVehicleCount + 1] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[j];
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[j] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[k];
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[k] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[towns[townNo].townVehicleCount + 1];
        }
        if (identical == -1) {
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[towns[townNo].townVehicleCount + 1] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[k];
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[k] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[j];
            towns[townNo].Vehicles[j] = towns[townNo].Vehicles[towns[townNo].townVehicleCount + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does happen? unsorted, unchanged, exception?

Comment: @HenkHolterman it does sort but it seems randomly. here
https://i.imgur.com/XC05W6t.jpg

Comment: If "towns[townNo].Vehicles" is of type "IEnumerable<T>", you can just call OrderBy(v=>v.Brand)

Comment: @AbdullahNehir It's not IEnumerable<T>. It's just simple class which holds strings and etc. here, take a look  http://pastebin.com/VMh73Ykk

Comment: Is seems you always swap elements `j` and `k` when they are different. Remove one of the `if` statements to only swap when the elements are not in correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was very simple!!

"Is seems you always swap elements j and k when they are different. Remove one of the if statements to only swap when the elements are not in correct order."

Thank you very much, @Henrik